# ActiveRecord has_many through chained filter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have projects with many materials and I am trying to make a chain of scope to filter them:

**project1** associated with **paper**.
**project2** associated with **plastic**

if the user click on **paper** I want that **project1** and **project2** are displayed. If after this first query user click on **plastic** I want to filter the first query result with the new constraint.

In other word if I select **paper** and **plastic** I only want to have **project2** displayed.

My models:

Project model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :project_materials
    has_many :materials, through: :project_materials

    scope :with_materials, -> (materials) { includes(:materials).where(materials: {id: materials} ) }
end
```

Material Model:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_materials
  has_many :projects, through: :project_materials
end
```

project_material Model:

```
class ProjectMaterial < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :material
end
```

I tried the following in the rails console:

```
p1 = Project.first
p2 = Project.last
m1 = Material.first
m2 = Material.last

p1.materials << m1

p2.materials << m1
p2.materials << m2

f1 = Project.with_materials(m1)
# which return p1 and p2

f2 = f1.with_materials(m2)
# which return nothings because of the following query

'SQL (1.0ms)  SELECT "projects"."id" AS t0_r0, "projects"."name" AS t0_r1, "projects"."difficulty" AS t0_r2, "projects"."status" AS t0_r3, "projects"."duration" AS t0_r4, "projects"."uuid" AS t0_r5, "projects"."slug" AS t0_r6, "projects"."created_at" AS t0_r7, "projects"."updated_at" AS t0_r8, "projects"."project_type_id" AS t0_r9, "materials"."id" AS t1_r0, "materials"."name" AS t1_r1, "materials"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "materials"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "project_materials" ON "project_materials"."project_id" = "projects"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "materials" ON "materials"."id" = "project_materials"."material_id" WHERE "materials"."id" = 5'
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't solve this purely on the model level. You would have to pass the constraint used on the first request the the second request by using params or the session.

Comment: hi the problem is if am passing both constraint in a array my result are p1 and p2 because the query will use a IN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution maybe not the most elegant but at least it's working.

```
def self.with_materials materials
  materials = [materials].flatten.compact

  sql = "SELECT project_id, count(material_id) FROM project_materials WHERE material_id IN (?) GROUP BY project_id HAVING count(material_id) > ?"
  ids = ProjectMaterial.find_by_sql [sql, (materials), (materials.count - 1)]
  ids.collect!{ |i| i.project_id }

  where( id: ids )
end
```